# How to create a contribution page that would create only Organisation record?

Tags: profile, contribution-page, organization, individual

I would like to create a contribution page where an organisation can donate.
But it seems an individual must be created first to be able to use on behalf of feature.
Is there a workaround to accept payment solely using organisation details only? Thanks

Comment: Not off hand but to address the front-end form "look" if you disable billing fields / use stripe processor you only need the individual's email address and use the " Check 'Required' to force ALL users to contribute/signup on behalf of an organization"option. Then you get pretty close with with out of the box config.